# Button event isn't firing after disabling the button in IE9 and IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer

I have a submit button on my page. On client click of submit button I'm using following Javascript function:

```
function SubmitDisable() {
var valid = Page_ClientValidate();
if (valid) {
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.cursor = "wait";
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").innerText = "Submitting...";

}
else {
    SubmitEnable();
    ApproveEnable();
   }
 }
```

It is working fine in `IE10`, `Chrome` and `Aurora` but not working in `IE9` and `IE8`.

Whenever I click on `submit button` it just gray out the `button` and change its text to Submitting and `page` hangs out. It doesn't `submit` the `page`.

How i can resolve this `issue` in `IE9` and `IE8`?
Looking forward for your replies.

Comment: have you tried this without disabling the button?

Comment: yes, before this functionality, it was working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like doing this with ASP.NET will require that you call the necessary `doPostBack` *after* the button has been disabled:

**Server-Side Implementation:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs e) {
  btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "SubmitDisable();" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, "").ToString());
}
```

OR

**Client-Side Implementation:**

```
function SubmitDisable() {
var valid = Page_ClientValidate();
if (valid) {
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.cursor = "wait";
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").innerText = "Submitting...";
    <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, "").ToString()%>
}
else {
    SubmitEnable();
    ApproveEnable();
   }
 }
```

Essentially this will add the following code to your function:

```
__doPostBack('MyPanel$btnSubmit','');
```

After disabling the button, forcing .NET to do a postback from the required control.

Comment: Thanks. Its working in `IE8` and `IE9`. I used the `Server-Side Implementation`. But i want to use the `client side Implementation`. I've written Disable function in separate `js` file. Its not supporting `Page.ClientScript` in `JS` file.  any alternate for this?

Comment: @CodeRider Yeah, that's a little more tough because you can't process GetPostBackEventReference in an external file. You would have to include the script on the page, or use the server-side version, or else pass a reference to the `doPostBack` through to your external file, i.e. put this in your .aspx page: `<script>function SubmitForm() { <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, "").ToString()%> }</script>` - then in your external javascript file you can just call `SubmitForm()` after disabling the button

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised by that, but it sounds like disabling the button is preventing the submission.

If so, you can delay disabling it by a human-imperceptible amount:

```
function SubmitDisable() {
    var valid = Page_ClientValidate();
    if (valid) {
        var btn = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
        btn.style.cursor = "wait";
        btn.innerText = "Submitting...";
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.disabled = true;
        }, 0);
    }
    else {
        SubmitEnable();
        ApproveEnable();
    }
}
```

That leaves the button enabled during the completion of the click event and form submission, but then within about 10 milliseconds or so, disables it.

Comment: let me try this one. :)

Comment: Sounds like ASP.Net getting in your way, rather than the browser.